# 2017 Community Moderator Election Results

Tags: discussion, election

Photography's [fifth moderator election](https://photo.stackexchange.com/election/5) has come to a close, the votes have been tallied, and the new moderator is:

[image: AJ Henderson]

They'll be joining [the existing crew](https://photo.stackexchange.com/users?tab=moderators) shortly — please thank them for volunteering, and share your assistance and advice with them as they learn the ropes!

For details on how the voting played out, you can download the election results [here](https://photo.stackexchange.com/election/5), or [view a summary report online](https://www.opavote.com/results/5319035331805184/0).

Answer (score 9):

Thank you for the vote of confidence everyone.  Looking forward to helping keep the ball rolling and helping make the Photography Stack Exchange the best photography resource around.

Comment: Congrats and welcome!

Answer (score 2):

Congrats AJ on another moderation spot!! :D

Answer (score 1):

Wasn't even close! Congratulations on your well deserved ♦, AJ Henderson!